# Scrolling with anchor in jquery lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I have a requirement to scroll to a paragraph on click of a link inside a light box. I tried using the below code

```
function goToByScroll(id) {
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}, 'slow');
}
```

This one scrolls the complete page at the background and not to the contents in the lightbox at front. I tried using the id of lightbox to animate instead of ('html,body') but no luck. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you create live demo

Comment: @Sasi Kumar M, did my answer helped you?!

Comment: @lonut, yes i had use the lightbox id instead of ('html','body') and it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this by using the id given to your paragraph:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#my_paragraph").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

I've made you a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pausghn3/1/)

You have to give your anchor the id 'button' and your paragraph the id 'my_paragraph' or whatever suits your needs.

Hope this helps.